# How to increase size of mesh?

Tags: three.js

Here's a demo of a rotating paper cup

https://jsfiddle.net/o5cd8g0h/

I want to increase the size of image in the cup, tried this

```
  logoMesh.scale.x = 1.5;
  logoMesh.scale.y = 1.5;
  logoMesh.scale.z = 1.5;
  logoMesh.position.set(0,-0.6,-0.6);
```

But the result is not what i expect https://jsfiddle.net/nL2spe5d/

 Image gets placed incorrectly

How to increase size of logoMesh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I get it, it depends on `logoFaceArray`. In simple words, it contains indices of faces. 6 faces on width, 8 faces on height.
Thus, if you want to make your logo mesh bigger, then you have to change this array of indices.

```
var logoFaceArray = [];
var multiplier = 2;
for(var lx = 0; lx < 6 * multiplier; lx++){
    for(var ly = 0; ly < 8 * multiplier; ly++){
    var index = 24 * lx + ly;
    logoFaceArray.push(index);
  }
}
```

Here you can play around with the `multiplier` variable, or you can leave it equal to 1, but change the limits of `lx` and `ly`, but remember that they (`lx`, `ly`) have to be even numbers, else you'll get a saw edge at the bottom of the logo.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/eu8h5z9g/) example